# Java Mail Hangs (after suspend?)

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using java mail 1.6 on Kubuntu Linux 18.04. It all works beautifully. I am connecting to an IMAP server, getting email, etc.

But there is one thing that is causing me grief.

After I close my laptop for a short period of time (so the laptop is probably sleeping), and then open it up, java mail keeps working just fine.

However after I close my laptop for a long period of time (overnight, so the laptop has probably suspended), and then I open it open it up, two things happen:

1. idle stops working (I have coded this with both IdleManager and
   folder.idle, and get the same issue)
2. when I close a Store or a Folder javamail simpy hangs.

I am guessing that somehow the TCP connection to the IMAP server has died, or maybe I have some timeout set wrong.

I would post code but its buried in a large application, and I am hoping someone has seen this issue before and it has a simple fix.

gym

Comment: You definitely need to set timeouts properly.  Detecting that the connection is broken depends on the OS.  Usually you need a thread that runs every so often to "poke" the server (e.g., folder.getMessageCount()) to cause it to try to send something to the server and thus discover that the connection is broken.

Comment: Oh, I thought IdleManager was "poking the server". So you are saying I need both IdleManager and another thread that periodically does something like folder.getMessageCount(). And what timeout params should I be looking to set? thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need another thread.  The timeouts depend on your mail server and how long you think your app can wait before declaring failure.

Comment: Ok, so if I have the other thread, do I need to re-initialize my JavaMail Store and Session if the connection times out? Or will IdleManager pick that up somehow and re-initialize the socket connections?

Comment: If the connection times out, you need to close the Folder and Store and reconnect and reopen them and rewatch the Folder.  The Session can continue to be used.